# how to close all running applications safely with c#

Tags: c#, process

how to close all running applications safely with c# without using windows logoff & shutdown API function. After closing all application i would like to show my application

Comment: i want to show my own login application which validates user against my online server database.

Comment: His next question: How to run unauthorized programs on a users computer from a website?

Comment: after login, i dont want to restrict applications run by user

Comment: You are trying to replace the windows login system?

Comment: i wont replace it, after login to windows my application asks username and password and allow users to work,and another application runs which shows some ad, which cannot be minimized. i have also provided logout button in desktop. after clicking logout my login application appears

Comment: so, your application will handle users' credentials, and show them ads?  pretty scary stuff.

Comment: This sounds like a reservation system, probably for schools or internet cafes. I'm currently building one for my school.

Answer (score 5):

If this is intended to be a replacement for the standard Windows login mechanism, you're not doing it right. On 2000/XP, consider writing a [custom](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742447.aspx) [GINA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx) [replacement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163786.aspx). On Vista/7, you need to write a new credential provider, as they got rid of the old GINA/Winlogon stack.

If you're trying to do a custom service of some sort instead, have you considered simply [switching desktops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682573(VS.85).aspx)? It's basically what Windows does for both Ctrl+Alt+Delete and the UAC "Secure Desktop." Far less work than killing the entire system and repopulating.

Seriously, reflect carefully on what you're about to do. The following is almost certainly the wrong thing, and may not always work with some programs:

```
// I mean it! This will cause badness!
using System.Diagnostics;

Process me = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (P.Id != me.Id)
        P.CloseMainWindow(); // Sends WM_CLOSE; less gentle methods available too
}
```

Comment: by using the above code, shutdown window appears. i would like to close without shutdown system

Comment: So add a bit more logic to the if statement. Make sure you're not trying to take down WinLogon.exe and similar processes. Consider P/Invoking to EnumWindows() and sending the WM_CLOSE call manually.

Comment: This is a gold answer. I was trying to close an application gracefully and didn't know CloseMainWindow existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through the running processes, and then you need to decide how "gentle" you want to be in closing other processess.  Note that sending a message, such as [WM_CLOSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632617(VS.85).aspx), will not force them to close.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this question is ancient, about 10-years old, however I wanted to expand a bit on ChrisV's code and give the code necessary to shutdown other applications without shutting down Windows. Checking "winlogon", not "winlogon.exe", does not work.

```
using System.Diagnostics.

Process me = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (p.Id != me.Id && IntPtr.Zero != p.MainWindowHandle && false == p.ProcessName.Equals("explorer", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // Sends WM_CLOSE; less gentle methods available too.
        p.CloseMainWindow();
    }
}
```

Additionally, run the above code with administrative privileges, so admin applications close too.

Note: File Explorer windows will stay open, as the Windows desktop is explorer.

I tested on Windows 10 and works great.

`Process.StartInfo.FileName` on Windows 10 returns empty strings, so targeting file names will not work.

Note: `p.MainWindowHandle` is zero if there is no main window, hence an application, but there are many cases which are not applications and still have a MainWindowHandle. I should know. I created an applet that displays non-zero MainWindowHandle and I saw many of them, but only had a couple of applications open, when I tested. Still, this code does prevent Windows from asking to shut down.

Comment: Would adding a wait timer for `p.CloseMainWindow` make sense before forcing via `p.Close()`?  I think this answer is an improvement though.  I'm curious about the `false == p.ProcessName.Equals...` haven't ever seen that style before.

Comment: @ParrishHusband I wanted to be more C#-ish than a mere == also take into account case, although "explorer" is always capitalized. I was thinking of adding an optional wait-loop along with monitoring but that would be more complicated and I was not comfortable with the thought. I wanted to keep things simple.